# how to create a timer.scheduler with name in java..?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am executing number of `Timer.schedulers` inside `run()`, I want to know the task taken by which scheduler. Please refer this code:

```
   Timer timer = new Timer();

   for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        timer.schedule(task, 5000);
    }
```

Here 10 times the task executing, but I cant able to find which task is taken by which timer. So checked the api there is no `setName()`. Is there any way to set the name for schedulers?

Please help me...

Comment: Okay is there any way to set the name for scheduler..??

Comment: You pass a reference of the `Timer` to the `task`...

Comment: can you please elaborate please submit your code..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either create a field name in you class extending `TimerTask` and provide getter/setters for it.

or in the run do: (this way you know which task was picked)

```
    public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("Task name");
     }
```

To know which scheduler is running, there is one constructor in Timer (refer the Timer source)

```
     /**
     * The timer thread. (and its the single thread to execute all the scheduled TimerTasks)
     */
  private final TimerThread thread = new TimerThread(queue);

  //Timer constructor
  public Timer(String name) {
            thread.setName(name);
            thread.start();
  }
```

so, use it as :

```
 Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimerName") 

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //will print timer name 
        System.out.println("Timer Name: "
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            //...

        }
    }
```

Don't set current thread's name in TimerTask's run for above case.